# Pygame scale messing up sprite

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a 2d top down game and I have a problem when I am zooming in/out and changing resolution.

[game start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDcy8.png)

[zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4nF2.png)

[zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz3Hb.png)

Here's the code that I'm using to manipulate the image(sprite):

```
char = pygame.image.load('char.png')
char_size = 10

def set_res(self,window_h):
    self.w = int(window_h * 1.2)#4:3
    self.h = int(window_h * 0.9)#4:3
    self.mode = (self.w, self.h)
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.mode)
    self.zoom()

def zoom(self):
    self.unit = self.h / self.board_units
    self.char = pygame.transform.scale(self.char, (int(self.unit*self.char_size),int(self.unit*self.char_size)))
.
.
.
self.screen.fill(self.white) 
self.screen.blit(self.char, (self.w/2-self.char_size*self.unit/2, self.h/2-self.char_size*self.unit/2))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
self.screen.blit(self.char, (self.w/2- self.char_size*self.unit/self.h/2-self.char_size*self.unit/2))
```

seems to be missing a comma in the tuple between left and top:

```
self.screen.blit(self.char, (self.w/2- self.char_size*self.unit, self.h/2-self.char_size*self.unit/2))
```

Also you already scaled the char, so just ask the `char` for a `rect` of its size, centered at the center of the screen:

```
self.screen.blit(self.char, self.char.get_rect(center=(self.w/2, self.h/2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what's wrong. I need to keep my original loaded image and use that image whenever I want to scale my sprite, otherwise, if I have 20x20 loaded image and scale it to 10x10 and then to 100x100, it's going to be a 10x10 image stretched to 100x100.